# Network access for ClickOnce applications

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce to deploy a .NET 6 Windows Form Applications. The application is used for two main purposes, launch TWAIN drivers (which may access network drives), and launch other applications (which also may access network paths).

When I build the application, and run it from the EXE.. Everything works fine (TWAIN drivers and other applications have network access when launched), but when I deploy it using ClickOnce and launch it using URL, those applications don't have network access.

I'm not very familiar with ClickOnce, is this a limitation from ClickOnce or am I missing some something?

Here is an example, my deployed ClickOnce application launches another console app. That console app accesses the network path.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: I tested by creating a minimal WinForms app to access a text file on a network drive, published using ClickOnce to a website and tested the deployed version -- no issues. You'll need to provide more details or a minimal reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: @rshepp see the added info.. Try to launch a console app from your deployed app then access the network path... Also make sure your network path is not mapped (no drive letter associated with it)